# Angular-universal MutationObserver problem

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, mutation-observers

I need to add angular-universal with ssr to an existing project. I followed [this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/universal), everything seemed fine except when I run the project. After I execute `npm run dev:ssr` I see `Compiled successfully` and this message:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Module.FARa (/home/project-path/dist/project/server/main.js:69075:26)
at __webpack_require__ (/home/project-path/dist/project/server/main.js:20:30)
at Module.JMXn (/home/project-path/dist/project/server/main.js:75830:74)
at __webpack_require__ (/home/project-path/dist/project/server/main.js:20:30)
at Module.PCNd (/home/project-path/dist/project/server/main.js:82492:109)
at __webpack_require__ (/home/project-path/dist/project/server/main.js:20:30)
at Module.ZAI4 (/home/project-path/dist/project/server/main.js:99022:79)
at __webpack_require__ (/home/project-path/dist/project/server/main.js:20:30)
at Module.24aS (/home/project-path/dist/project/server/main.js:41256:69)
at __webpack_require__ (/home/project-path/dist/project/server/main.js:20:30)
```

Comment: If this is your own code, don't use `window` objects when the code is executed server side. Otherwise, try adding `domino` to your `server.ts`

Comment: I've added domino and added if(window) everywhere window is used, still got this problem

Comment: You need to dig in the compiled code to see which module is trying to use it

Comment: I also have same issue on upgrading to angular 13 with SSR

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
global['MutationObserver'] = getMockMutationObserver();

function getMockMutationObserver() {
  return class {
    observe(node, options) {}
    disconnect() {}
    takeRecords() {
      return [];
    }
  };
}
```

credit: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/issues/298